# Unable to direct insert in mysql database from linux xshell

Tags: mysql, linux, opensuse

i have run below command to insert data into my mysql database. sql query is ok. but after run the query, a prompt is coming to enter the password. but in my database no password is set. SO if i press enter key without writing anything then it is inserting data. How can i avoid to this prompt. That means i want that command will be directly working. No prompt will come for Enter Password.

```
Enter password: 
linux-pott:/opt/lampp/htdocs # mysql -uroot -p  -e 'insert into dialer_rate(date_time,time,mno,trx_type,trx_result,trx_value) values("2015-02-19","12:14","air","N/A","Not_Running",0) ' bkash
Enter password: 
linux-pott:/opt/lampp/htdocs #
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the option `-p` in your cmd:

```
linux-pott:/opt/lampp/htdocs # mysql -u root -e 'insert into dialer_rate(date_time,time,mno,trx_type,trx_result,trx_value) values("2015-02-19","12:14","air","N/A","Not_Running",0) ' bkash
```

From the official [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/command-line-options.html):

> For a long option that takes a value, separate the option name and the value by an “=” sign. For a short option that takes a value, the option value can immediately follow the option letter, or there can be a space between: -hlocalhost and -h localhost are equivalent. An exception to this rule is the option for specifying your MySQL password. This option can be given in long form as --password=pass_val or as --password. In the latter case (with no password value given), the program prompts you for the password. The password option also may be given in short form as -ppass_val or as -p. However, for the short form, if the password value is given, it must follow the option letter with no intervening space. The reason for this is that if a space follows the option letter, the program has no way to tell whether a following argument is supposed to be the password value or some other kind of argument. Consequently, the following two commands have two completely different meanings: